# Hugging face Model Output 'last_hidden_state'

Tags: pytorch, bert, huggingface, bart

I am using the Huggingface BERTModel, The model gives **Seq2SeqModelOutput** as output. The output contains the past hidden states and the last hidden state.
These are my questions

1. What is the use of the hidden states?
2. How do I pass my hidden states to my output layer?
3. What I actually want is the output tokens, from the model how do I get the prediction tokens?